# Photos don't show up in News Feed on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos, feed, facebook-timeline, facebook-ios-sdk

Uploaded photos through Graph API "me/photos" aren't showing up in News Feed on Facebook. But the photos are added in albums successfully and shows up in Timeline only. I'm sure that it worked a few months ago, but today I found it wasn't working now. Unfortunately I didn't find any clues in Facebook developers website and any change logs about News Feed. Do I have to call another Graph API to list uploaded photos?

```
NSArray *permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil] retain];    
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
...
...
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               image, @"picture",
                               commentView.text, @"message",
                               nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Have you tried manually calling the POST request using native NSURLConnection? You could also try a networking library like ASIHTTPRequest to simplify your binary upload.